# Could not build ClassFile - ArchiveException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

We develop an application with spring, jpa, tomcat, maven, etc.

Locally on my developer machine everything works fine but when we deploy the application on a linux server I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    org.domain.application.persistence.repository.DataSourceConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(DataSourceConfiguration.java:78)
    org.domain.application.persistence.repository.DataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52a56856.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$0(<generated>)
    org.domain.application.persistence.repository.DataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52a56856$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44eff5a3.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    org.domain.application.persistence.repository.DataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52a56856.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:446)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The exception appears in my code after initializing the database when I call this method:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()
```

Can't find the problem. Help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I had the same symptom which in my case, was related to icu4j transitively included and repackaged into the same jar, which made javaassist scan icu4j classes too, which so happens to run into a class (com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class) that javassist can't parse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000933/master-slave), I found the problem, as he describes there is a conflict with a incompatible java 8 library of javassist.

In my case, it was a dependency of tiles:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Correct!!!
I used your suggestion and my Exception solved.Thank You.

By the way, I exclude the java assist from my org.apache.struts too.

 <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles3-plugin</artifactId>

Comment: I ran into this issue with LightAdmin. Turns out it references tiles AND javassist, so you need to exclude javassist from jboss and org.javassist groupIds. Thanks @master-slave and myborobudur for saving my day!

Comment: I had a same issue when I added the dependency to concordion:2.0.2. Solution is the same:
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
            <artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 36):

The issue can be a conflict between a java version and a javaassist version. If you're using the java 8 on your server you should make sure to use the latest javassist version as well. This [blog](http://qkyrie.silvrback.com/spring-thymeleaf-and-java-8) shows the origin of a conflict being inside the thymeleaf which pulls in an older  javassist, the solution being to exclude it from the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

your case could be different, so you should inspect the dependency tree to find a suitable solution

Comment: The problem was an older version of the `javassist` library. But I don't understand way this was not an issue on my local machine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: thymeleafwas my case too

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same issue, in that it worked fine on a development machine and then failed in production.

The reason can be seen if you build the war file locally and then unzip it. You'll see you end up with two javassist jars:

```
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
```

which will just be deployed together in the same `lib` folder. So when your java application loads and it requires a class from the *javassist* library it will search the classpath and *probably* encounter the first (and incorrect) jar and load it.

This *probably* doesn't happen locally because your buld tool (maven, or in my case gradle) constructs a long intricate classpath of specific resources, in which it *probably* specifies the compatible version first which makes it *more probable* that the classpath search will find it.

(I keep saying *probable* because it will depend on how the classpath searching has been implemented and I think this can depend on the JVM, and other things, but I don't have the impetus to look it up right now but will add it to my TODO list and get back to you... or if anyone else knows the answer please just edit this post!)

Anway, for any `gradle` users out there I solved the problem with the following snippet:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'javassist', module: 'javassist' // get rid of hibernate-incompatible javassist
}
```

I had to use a global exclusion because the javassist-3.11 library (group: 'javassist') was being pulled in as a dependency of a dependency of a dependency and hibernate wanted the javassist-3.18 library (group: 'org.javassist') instead.

Thanks to all invovled, especially [master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000933/master-slave).

Comment: Same if you encounter javassist-3.12.x.GA.jar.

Answer (score 12):

I had a same issue when tried to deploy Java 8 application to Weblogic 12.1.3c.
What i did is add this to **weblogic.xml**:

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: this helped me resolve the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding the below dependency might solve the issue.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.22.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: works for me. Does anybody know what this library is, and how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading below plugin dependency from 2.1 to 3.2.1 solved the issue for me
            `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>`

Comment: This worked for me too! Anyway is there any specific reason for this on why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I got same exception. I use java 8, hibernate, jpa, jetty.

I solved it by updating these to the latest available version:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.11.Final'
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception is due to wrong/conflict version of javassist, find out using this command -->

```
    mvn dependency:tree | grep javassist
```

Then resolve it by excluding that version of javassist like this -->

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.11</version>
        <exclusions>        
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the solution was to upgrade these hibernate dependencies, this way (version with problem was 5.2.1.Final):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with thymleaf 3.0.0.BETA01 and two different javaassist versions. Thymeleaf pulls javaassist 3.11(which causes the error).

Here is the fixed pom-entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.BETA01</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Make your own analysis

If `javassist` is not your dependency problem, you'll have to make your own dependency analysis. This is what I did.

1. Locate conflicts by extracting the dependencies and see different versions of the same library. I executed `mvn dependency:list | sort --unique > dependencies_list.txt` to generate a dependencies sorted file with only one line per library version. This way was easier to locate duplicate entries for the same library.
2. Locate where each dependency is imported. With the already suggested `mvn dependency:tree > dependency_tree.txt` you get the dependencies tree where you can search for the dependency hierarchy that brings in each of the versions in conflict.
3. Once located the libraries that bring the different versions of the conflict, try updating their versions or excluding the element that makes the conflict from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Error: I got following error

```
Apr 04, 2022 4:22:07 PM org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication reportFailure
SEVERE: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primaryEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [/PrimarConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$2936.0000000027F3B530.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1394)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1331)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1317)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1834)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:764)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:61)
    ... 70 more
```

**Solution**:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an older version of Wildfly that provides older versions of Hibernate and javassist.  Although the setup is java 8 compatible, some of the newer java 8 compatible libraries in our .sar file (*cough* jackson-core.jar) include a module-info.class to assist with java 9 modularity.  This module-info.class is compiled under java 9.  When javassist interrogates the module-info.class, it can't handle the java 9 class structure and throws the ArchiveException.