# Can't get Spring-Boot & Hibernate working as a named module in Java 9

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, java-9

Exploring Java 9, trying to migrate an example Spring-Boot Hibernate app from Java 8 to Java 9 and running into the below issue.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@1.5.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at restfulpeople@1.0/com.khs.restful.people.RestfulPeopleApplication.main(RestfulPeopleApplication.java:14) [restfulpeople-1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@4.3.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 20 at 7
    at javassist@3.22.0-CR1/javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1244) ~[javassist-3.22.0-CR1.jar:na]
    at javassist@3.22.0-CR1/javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1175) ~[javassist-3.22.0-CR1.jar:na]
    at javassist@3.22.0-CR1/javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:185) ~[javassist-3.22.0-CR1.jar:na]
    at javassist@3.22.0-CR1/javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:839) ~[javassist-3.22.0-CR1.jar:na]
    at javassist@3.22.0-CR1/javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:164) ~[javassist-3.22.0-CR1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.9.SNAPSHOT]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

I was able to get this application working as [an unnammed module and importing my entire lib directory](https://github.com/wkorando/restful-people/tree/01-classpath), but have been stuck with the above exception for awhile now when trying to run the app as a single "monolithic module".

Googling the specific error I am getting brings me to this stackoverflow thread: [Could not build ClassFile - ArchiveException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202939/could-not-build-classfile-archiveexception)

Can't really figure if that's relevant or not. Have only a single copy of javassist of classapth/modulepath and it's the latest release version of the library. Also, as previously mentioned this application does work as an unammed-module (so that would seem to suggest it isn't a version conflict issue).

Here is the build file I am using right now to launch the app:

```
set -e

CLASSPATH=mods/accessors-smart-1.1.jar:mods/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:mods/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/antlr-2.7.7.jar:mods/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/asm-5.0.3.jar:mods/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:mods/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/assertj-core-2.6.0.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/classmate-1.3.3.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/evo-inflector-1.2.1.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/h2-1.4.193.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/hamcrest-modsrary-1.3.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-test-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:mods/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:mods/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:mods/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:mods/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:mods/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:mods/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:mods/spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar:mods/spring-data-rest-core-2.6.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:mods/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:mods/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:mods/spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:mods/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/json-path-2.2.0.jar:mods/spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/json-smart-2.2.1.jar:mods/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:mods/jsonassert-1.4.0.jar:mods/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:mods/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:mods/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:mods/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:mods/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:mods/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:mods/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:mods/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:mods/objenesis-2.1.jar:mods/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:mods/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:mods/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:mods/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:mods/spring-boot-test-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:mods/spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:mods/junit-4.12.jar:mods/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar

javac -cp $CLASSPATH \
      --module-path mods \
      -d out         \
      --module-source-path src $(find src -name '*.java')

jar --create --file mods/restfulpeople-1.0.jar --module-version=1.0 -C out/restfulpeople .

java -cp $CLASSPATH \
     --module-path mods       \
     --add-modules java.xml.bind,java.sql,javassist,spring.core,spring.beans,java.instrument \
     --add-opens java.base/java.lang=javassist \
     --add-opens java.base/java.lang=spring.core \
     --add-opens java.base/java.lang=spring.beans \
     -m restfulpeople/com.khs.restful.people.RestfulPeopleApplication
```

And here is a link to my github repo for local testing purposes: https://github.com/wkorando/restful-people/tree/02-monolithic-module

Let me know if additional information is needed.

EDIT:

Added underlying exception. New constant pool types (in the case of this specific error CONSTANT_Package) were added in the jigsaw edition of java 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175089

Comment: We haven't yet certified Hibernate to run on JDK9, just FYI.

Comment: Yea, definitely realize this is on the bleeding edge and *might* literally not be possible yet. But guess some unlucky individual needs to run into these issues first? I am basing my project heavily on the work by Sander Mak & Paul Bakker here: https://github.com/sandermak/java9-migration-demos/tree/master/3_MonolithicSpring, that does work, however it's not using spring boot. Now inspecting boot code for issues: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: Understood, well its likely worth mentioning we are doing CI against JDK9 with each push and aware of the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

20 is the CONSTANT_Package but you should only see these tags in the constant pool of module-info.class. It may be the version of Javaassist used in the experiment doesn't support JDK 9 and version 53.0 class file yet.