# Java PersistenceException if executed as jar

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm currently building a Discord Bot with [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) and I'm trying to add a Database Connection with Hibernate. If I execute the Program inside IntelliJ it works without any errors. But after I compiled the Project and execute the jar file, I get this error: (My goal is to execute the bot in a docker container.)

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at ch.ydavid.pizzabot.DAO.GuildConfigDAO.<init>(GuildConfigDAO.java:12)
        at ch.ydavid.pizzabot.manager.DynamicVoiceManager.<init>(DynamicVoiceManager.java:18)
        at ch.ydavid.pizzabot.manager.GeneralManager.<init>(GeneralManager.java:5)
        at ch.ydavid.pizzabot.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
        ... 6 more
```

I already checked the jar file for the javax.persistence dependency and the persistence.xml file. They are both provided in the Jar.

My source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/YesterDavid135/Pizza-Bot/tree/add_jpa). (add_jpa branch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not build ClassFile - ArchiveException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202939/could-not-build-classfile-archiveexception)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks, but I already tried to change the java versions but that didn't worked.

Comment: its not about java versions per se. its about javassist dependecy (maybe also tyhmeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the artifact by going on

```
File > Project Structure > Artifacts
```

then delete the current one and create a new one by going on

```
+ > Jar > From Modules With Dependencies
```

Add your main class then click OK and Apply. Then to build the artifact go on

```
File > Build > Build Artifacts > Build
```

If it doesn't work this way please add a comment/answer to this post